# Why the texture does not show on my object?

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

Here are my files for the stuff I show below: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0fraun9z3psbges/AACu2uOLH4eCNEiU-cFfv3-la?dl=0

- manual.obj has `usemtl 2imagesconcatenated`
- manual.mtl has `newmtl 2imagesconcatenated` and 
  `map_Kd imageBlendedBefore.png`
- material is applied:

[image: Material is applied]

- the UV Map is selected (and with Viewport set to Material):

[image: The UV Map is selected]

When the viewport is set to Texture:

[image: viewport set to Texture]

When viewport is set to Rendered:

[image: viewport is set to Rendered]

---

**I would like to see my texture applied to my object. What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .obj file is improperly set

Should be

```
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4
f 3/3/3 4/4/4 5/5/5
f 4/4/4 5/5/5 6/6/6
```

instead of

```
f 1 2 3
f 2 3 4
f 3 4 5
f 4 5 6
```

and vt values should be between 0 and 1